# Undefined al imprimir atributo de un objeto

Tags: javascript

estoy obteniendo un cliente por una api realizada en node js, desde el front, cuando quiero mapear los datos, me muestra undefined, pero si imprimo el objeto lo imprime bien

```
function mostrarCliente(cliente){
console.log(cliente.data)
const { id, email, nombre, empresa, telefono} = cliente.data;
console.log(cliente)
nombreInput.value = nombre;
empresaInput.value = empresa;
telefonoInput.value = telefono;
emailInput.value = email;
idInput.value = id;
avatarinput.value = avatar;
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estás tratando de acceder a las propiedades de un objeto que se encuentra dentro de un arreglo. Dicho de otro modo, `cliente.data` es un arreglo de objetos, es por eso que si tratas de acceder directamente obtienes undefined. Para que funcione tienes que acceder al elemento cero de ese arreglo: `... = cliente.data[0];`

Comment: Gracias funciono de esa manera, se puede conseguir obtener el valor de la propiedad de otra forma?

Comment: Si tienes acceso al código del backend podrías comprobar si solo hay un resultado y devolverlo directamente en lugar de devolver el array. Si no, la única forma es que hagas esa comprobación antes de intentar hacer la destructuración de los valores.